# Uninstall Widget from emulator

Tags: android

I changed the name etc of the widget I'm developing, I'm having trouble uninstalling the old one from the emulator.  How does one uninstall widget on the emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove widgets by long-pressing on them, then a delete handle gets shown on the bottom of the screen. Drag the widget above it and release *(a press is a mouseclick in the emulator, so long-hold the mousebutton)*.

Or you can uninstall the whole app that contains the widget. Then you get an *"error displaying widget"* message where the widget was placed, so you still have to use the above method to remove it completely. To do so either use `Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications` from the emulator, or execute `adb uninstall your.apps.packagename` from the command line of your computer.

Comment: Didn't know about the Settings, thnx

Answer (score 1):

One long clicks the widget, and drags it to the trash can icon. Is there only a widget in your apk? Does it not show in Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications?

Comment: Didn't know about the Settings, thnx